# How can I clean up my MediaPlayer after use? -Android Studio

Tags: android, button, onclick, media-player

Please tell me based on an example how I can clean up my MediaPlayer after use.

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{


        MediaPlayer mp;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        }


    //sound onClick's
    public void sound1(View view){
        mp= MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound1);
        mp.start();
    }
    public void sound2(View view){
        mp= MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound2);
        mp.start();
    }
    public void sound3(View view){
        mp= MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound3);
        mp.start();
    }
    public void sound4(View view){
        mp= MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound4);
        mp.start();
    }

}
```

I know that I have to use mp.release() but it doesn't work if I write:

```
public void sound1(View view){
            mp= MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound1);
            mp.start();
            mp.release();
        }
```

Please give me an example.
This is very important for me :)

Answer (score 0):

First point, you shouldn't call start() and release () method one after another.

This is how you should play and release your media player.

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this,Uri.parse("android.resource://app/raw/sound")); 
mp.preapare();
mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() { 
 @Override 
 public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp)
 { 
    mp.release(); 
 } }); 
mp.start();
```